# Heroku shows blank white page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

When I deployed my app to heroku, I got a blank white page with the following errors:

Link: https://jenlky-shopping-cart.herokuapp.com/

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://jenlky-shopping-cart.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.bbad26e2.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. 2.65283897.chunk.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 2.65283897.chunk.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.221452bc.chunk.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 2.65283897.chunk.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.221452bc.chunk.js:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) favicon.ico:1

Refused to apply style from 'https://jenlky-shopping-cart.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.bbad26e2.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

`heroku local` produces a blank white page too with less errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/static/css/main.d60d3cf9.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

4localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:5000/static/js/1.b7d12b63.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

manifest.json:1 GET http://localhost:5000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

Any idea how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you referenced the stylesheets correctly? Double check you have spelt it right. For example `styles.css` not `style.css`

Comment: You cannot use `localhost` to refer to yourself in Heroku